# Zooming Entire ScrollView

Tags: ios4, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a series of PDFScrollViews (like the one given in the sample code on Apple Developer) inside a UIScrollView but I want them to all scroll at once no matter where in the ScrollView the Pinch-Zoom action happens, currently this only happens to the one PDFScrollView that is pinched and the other stay the same size.  The basic goal I'm trying to achieve here is to make a series of PDFs act as one homogeneous PDF to the user.

Answer (score 0):

implement scroll view's delegate method
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView: (UIScrollView *) ScrollView
And return your  PDF view.
hope it 'll work